# Can a process perform IO while residing in secondary memory?

Tags: operating-system

I am confused about suspend wait and block terms in operating system. 
I read it as a process which is in wait or block state needs to be thrown in sec memory and resumes with main memory after completing IO.

Can a process perform IO while residing in secondary memory?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely upon the operating system and hardware. Some system do allow this. Others do not. It is a lot of fun porting software from a system that does to a system that does not.